# Why is action 'eosio::setcode' on the action blacklist in the mainnet?

Tags: smart-contract, mainnet

Error 3130005: Action to execute is on the blacklist
Error Details:
action 'eosio::setcode' is on the action blacklist
pending console output:

in mainnet

Why is this?

Comment: seems the mainnet is maintaining

Answer (score 1):

It was mentioned on the Telegram channel for developers that a bug has been found, so the BPs blacklisted the command until it's fixed. No other details were provided for now, but some BPs mentioned that a more detailed report should be coming soon. There's also [an issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4821) raised on GitHub about this.

---

Post-mortem explanation thanks to Kevin Rose from EOS New York who saved Bart Wyatt's explanation from July 26th:

> Now that mainnet is safe I can provide more details.  Several
>   versions ago we subjectively disabled implicit re-scheduling of
>   deferred transaction because they did not properly refund RAM.  That
>   also disabled a pretty nasty bug that we were unaware of until
>   yesterday.  1.1.1 fixed a source of non-determinism but in doing so,
>   changed the behavior of a corner case in processing such that 1.1.1
>   producers could make blocks that appeared to reschedule a deferred
>   transaction to 1.1.0 producers.  This lead to those producers thinking
>   that a later block was invalid (due to the nasty bug).  It was a razor
>   thin edge case so, of course jungle hit it.
>
> To make matters worse, the order in which jungle producers were set up
>   created a stubborn forking scenario where the 1.1.1 producers were
>   able to convince themselves of a superior chain despite it being the
>   minority fork so they never rejoined concensus and the 1.1.0 producers
>   thought the superior chain was invalid due to a bad block.  It will
>   take them a while to coordinate and select a proper main chain.  Until
>   those producers all upgrade to 1.1.1 it can happy again
>
> And the last part of their issue is that there is some additional
>   historical block made by a 1.1.0 producer (or earlier) that is failing
>   replay on 1.1.1 .  We saw no such blocks in the mainnet and they are
>   not producible by 1.1.1 so, again mainnet is safe.  Had we seen that
>   before the release or on mainnet we would have tried to address it
>   before patch but, replaying jungle was not yet on our acceptance tests
>   (it will be now, as well as other busy community testnets)”
>
> The two releases referenced in the above: July 17th - 
>   https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.1.0  July 24th -
>   https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.1.1
>
> The following was listed as a critical issue in the v1.1.1 release
>   notes.  Self-Cancelling Deferred Transactions Calling
>   cancel_deferred(sender_id) using the sender_id of the currently
>   executing deferred transaction was not properly handled. This has been
>   resolved so that the cancel_deferred call semantics match the
>   expectation that passing invalid or already-retired sender_id is a
>   no-op. The currently executing transaction is considered "retired" WRT
>   these semantics. Unit test added
>   https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/083935ea0e4fa93e1a4a101164fe3e6182c8fcac/contracts/test_api/test_transaction.cpp#L321-L339
>
> https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/commit/083935ea0e4fa93e1a4a101164fe3e6182c8fcac